# Does fread fail for large files?

Tags: c, large-files, fread

I have to analyze a 16 GB file. I am reading through the file sequentially using `fread()` and `fseek()`. Is it feasible? Will `fread()` work for such a large file?

Comment: Can you clarify the language used?

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and guess C

Comment: do fread and fseek even exist as standards in another language?

Answer (score 6):

You don't mention a language, so I'm going to assume C.

I don't see any problems with `fread`, but `fseek` and `ftell` may have issues.

Those functions use `long int` as the data type to hold the file position, rather than something intelligent like `fpos_t` or even `size_t`.  This means that they can fail to work on a file over 2 GB, and can certainly fail on a 16 GB file.

You need to see how big `long int` is on your platform.  If it's 64 bits, you're fine.  If it's 32, you are likely to have problems when using `ftell` to measure distance from the start of the file.

Consider using `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` instead.

Comment: The comment *"..you can't legally use non-zero `fseek` offsets without a call to `ftell`"* is only true for files opened in text mode.  Files opened in binary mode can use `SEEK_SET` and `SEEK_CUR` with arbitrary offsets.

Comment: @caf:  Thanks.  My answer has been changed as you suggested.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the response. I figured out where I was going wrong. `fseek()` and `ftell()` do not work for files larger than 4GB. I used `_fseeki64()` and `_ftelli64()` and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

If implemented correctly this shouldn't be a problem.  I assume by sequentially you mean you're looking at the file in discrete chunks and advancing your file pointer.

Check out http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/using-fread-with-a-large-file-/10254.html

It sounds like he was doing nearly the same thing as you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do. If you want to read the whole 16GB of data in memory, then chances are that you'll run out of memory or application heap space.

Rather read the data chunk by chunk and do processing on those chunks (and free resources when done).

But, besides all this, decide which approach you want to do (using `fread()` or `istream`, etc.) and do some test cases to see which works better for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a POSIX-ish system, you'll need to make sure you've built your program with 64-bit file offset support. POSIX mandates (or at least allows, and most systems enforce this) the implementation to deny IO operations on files whose size don't fit in `off_t`, even if the only IO being performed is sequential with no seeking.

On Linux, this means you need to use `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` on the `gcc` command line.