# Handling big files on 32bit machine with gcc

Tags: gcc, 32-bit

How do i handle big files (>10 GB) with c (at least reading them)? I don't have a 64bit machine, so the compiler Option 
`-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks likely to be a duplicate of [Reading a large file using C (greater than 4GB) using read function, causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790822/reading-a-large-file-using-c-greater-than-4gb-using-read-function-causing-pro)

Since you mention GCC, I'm assuming Linux, Solaris, or something similar.  If you are using GCC on Windows, I don't know if the following will hold true.

If you just `open` the file with `O_LARGEFILE` and use `read`, it should work, provided that you don't try to keep the entire file in memory and that your `read` size is under 32 bits in size.  Same for `write`.  If you need to seek, use `lseek64` and compile with `#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` (note, `lseek64` is not entirely standard, so if you aren't on Linux, the `lseek` man page will hopefully point you to the prefered solution).