# How to read a large file with function read() in C

Tags: c, file-io

Aloha,

I'm new here, so please take it easy on me.
I'm trying to read a file with function `read()` and then `write()` to a file or a  file descriptor. My function successfully reads a file, but a problem occurs when I try to read a larger file(in my example size of 40,000 bytes).

I think that I must write a while loop, which will be reading until the end of a file, but I am stuck on the idea of how to..

(I open a file or file descriptor in main of the program)

My function( also convert binary input char data and writes to the ASCII) :

```
void function(int readFrom,int writeOn){
    char buffer[100];
    int x = read(readFrom, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    int size= x/8;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        char temp[sizeof(int)-1];
        sprintf(temp,"%d",buffer[i];
        write(writeOn, temp, sizeof(temp));
    }
}
```

Comment: `size(int)-1` isn't really a big buffer.

Comment: Show the "example" of 40k read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a large file using C (greater than 4GB) using read function, causing problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790822/reading-a-large-file-using-c-greater-than-4gb-using-read-function-causing-pro)

Comment: this statement: `int size= x/8;` uses integer math, so if the amount of bytes read is not a multiple of 8, some bytes will never be processed.  Since 100 is not a multiple of 8, you can expect to miss outputting 4 bytes for every pass through the outer loop.   Also, when the `read()` fails to input 100 bytes, the execution can be expected to lose upto 7 bytes for every pass through the outer loop.   Much better to read 1024 bytes and use the returned value from `read()` as the count for the call to `write()`

Comment: @reny310: You can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check return value of functions `read` and `write`. They return the number of bytes read/written that may be less than the number that you passed as third argument. Both `read` and `write` must be done in a loop like:

```
int bytesRead = 0;

while (bytesRead < sizeof(buffer)) {
    int ret = read(readFrom, buffer + bytesRead, sizeof(buffer) - bytesRead);

    if (ret == 0)
        break; / * EOF */

    if (ret == -1) {
        /* Handle error */
    }

    bytesRead += ret;
}
```

Comment: If you reach EOF before you fill the buffer, you're stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

You use `sprintf()` to convert characters from `buffer` into a very small buffer `temp`. On most current systems, `int` is 4 bytes, so your printf causes buffer overflows for `char` values greater than `99` (ASCII letter `'c'`).  Note that `char` can be signed by default, so negative values less than `-99` will require 5 bytes for the string conversion: 3 digits, a minus sign and a null terminator.

You should make this buffer larger.

Furthermore, I don't understand why you only handle `x/8` bytes from the buffer read by the `read()` function.  The purpose of your function is obscure.